# Object type looks weird when construct has std::less as argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2013 is giving me an error on the following code. When I construct the object, it reports that a1 is not a class/struct/union. I am not sure exactly what the problem with this code is. It seems like if a2 is not reporting an error, a1 should not either.

If I mouse over a1, it says its type is "A a1(std::less(*)())" and a2 just shows "A a2" which is what I would expect.

Anyone have any ideas of what is going on here? Thanks.

```
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
    A(const std::less<int> &a) { }
    void foo() { }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a1(std::less<int>());
    A a2 = A(std::less<int>());

    a1.foo(); // Error: "left of '.foo' must have class/struct/union"
    a2.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's because you declare `a1` to be a function which takes `std::less<int>` as argument and returns an `A` object. Related to [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you. That explains a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a victim of [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

in `A a1(std::less<int>());` , which declares

`a1` as a function which takes `std::less<int>` as argument and returning object of type `A`

---

Force the compiler to consider this as a variable definition for `a1` using :

```
A a1( ( std::less<int>()    ));
    //^  notice parenthesis ^
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
A a1(std::less<int>());
```

is a function declaration that has return type `A` and a parameter of type `std::less<int>().` Write instead

```
A a1 { std::less<int>() };
```

or

```
A a1( ( std::less<int>() ) );
```